# Unabel to get json file from local server

Tags: javascript, json, api, koa

I want to write a server API with **Koa**, this server provides a single API endpoint, **/api/data**. when user enter ***localhost:3000/api/data*** in browser, server read a **json** file from local and show it in browser.

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const serve = require('koa-static');
const Router = require('koa-router');
// const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

app.use(serve('.'));

router.get('/api/data', async (ctx, next) => {
  await fs.readFile('./data.json','utf-8', (err, data) => {
    ctx.body = JSON.parse(data);
  });
});

app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());
app.listen(3000);
```

It does not work. the error message is 404, i don't known where something went wrong. i just started learning Koa, pls help me!

Comment: you should check if the file you are trying to read is on that path that you have provided `fs.readFile('./data.json'`

Comment: the data.json file is on that path

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFile` does not return a promise, that's why `koa` will not wait until it finishes, and once it reaches the end of your middleware function, if the body is still empty will return you the 404 page.

For this reason you need to promisify all your asynchronous functions, or use their synchronous version.

Your middleware should look like this:

```
router.get('/api/data', async (ctx) => {
    // utf8 is required, without it fs.readFileSync will return you a buffer
    let data = fs.readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf8')
    ctx.body = JSON.parse(data);
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

You can stream that file. It may be more easier:

```
router.get('/api/data', async (ctx, next) => {
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream('./data.json','utf8');
  ctx.body = readStream;
  await next();
});
```

Use `ctx.body` to push out the data instead of `await fs.readFile()`, which just returns to nowhere.

**UPDATE**

I guess you should remove `app.use(serve('.'));` and place this middleware after router middlewares:

```
app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods())
  .use(serve('.'));
```

Comment: You don't need to `await next()` if you return the response body in current middleware, and the 404 error shows up when the middleware chain ended and `ctx.body` is still empty.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! We don't need `await next()`. but it's still need ctx.body to output response. I had updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Need add to `ctx.response.body='application/json' ` is perfect. Thanks a lot.